# Crashlytics Send to Reports Endpoint disabled

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

Im not able to get crash reports on Crashlytics.
I noticed that logcat says that "Send to Reports Endpoint disabled."

Any ideas how to enable sending reports?
Also another strange thing is that my API key in project settings does not match with key in google-services.json. Not sure if this is related.

===================================
2020-09-06 12:27:27.633 19384-19384/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics is handling uncaught exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: This is a crash" from thread main
2020-09-06 12:27:28.353 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing open sessions.
2020-09-06 12:27:28.353 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Closing session: 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.354 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting session parts for ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.355 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E has fatal exception: true
2020-09-06 12:27:28.357 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Session 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E has non-fatal exceptions: false
2020-09-06 12:27:28.358 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionStart data for session ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.361 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionUser data for session ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.363 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionApp data for session ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.365 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionOS data for session ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.368 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Collecting SessionDevice data for session ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.371 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing session part files for ID 5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:28.976 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Opening a new session with ID 5F54AB8003CD-0002-4BB8-0541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:29.003 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics automatic data collection ENABLED by firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled manifest flag.
2020-09-06 12:27:29.025 19384-19575/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Logging Crashlytics event to Firebase
2020-09-06 12:27:29.027 19384-19575/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Awaiting app exception callback from FA...
2020-09-06 12:27:29.272 19384-19497/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/TransportRuntime.SQLiteEventStore: Storing event with priority=HIGHEST, name=FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_REPORT for destination cct
2020-09-06 12:27:29.352 19384-19497/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/TransportRuntime.JobInfoScheduler: Scheduling upload for context TransportContext(cct, HIGHEST, MSRodHRwczovL2NyYXNobHl0aWNzcmVwb3J0cy1wYS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS92MS9maXJlbG9nL2xlZ2FjeS9iYXRjaGxvZ1xBSXphU3lCcnBTWVQ0RkZMMDlyZUhKaTZIOUZZZGVpU25VVE92Mk0=) with jobId=1541223086 in 23420ms(Backend next call timestamp 1599384472767). Attempt 1
2020-09-06 12:27:29.371 19384-19495/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Received Analytics message: 3 Bundle[{params=Bundle[{_o=clx, _r=1, _et=6172, _sc=ActivityHome, _si=3809957349711409662, timestamp=1599384447633, fatal=1}], name=_ae, timestampInMillis=1599384449026}]
2020-09-06 12:27:29.373 19384-19575/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: App exception callback received from FA listener.
2020-09-06 12:27:29.377 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics report successfully enqueued to DataTransport: 5F54AB7503E700014BB80541ED97291E
2020-09-06 12:27:29.381 19384-19384/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics completed exception processing. Invoking default exception handler.
2020-09-06 12:27:29.387 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
2020-09-06 12:27:29.389 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Send to Reports Endpoint disabled. Removing Reports Endpoint report.
2020-09-06 12:27:29.390 19384-19494/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 D/FirebaseCrashlytics: Removing report at /data/user/0/lv.molssoft.geoempire2/files/.com.google.firebase.crashlytics/fatal-sessions/5F54AB7503E7-0001-4BB8-0541ED97291E.cls
2020-09-06 12:27:29.401 19384-19495/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 6315
2020-09-06 12:27:29.432 19384-19384/lv.molssoft.geoempire2 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19384 SIG: 9

Comment: [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434528/crashlytics-not-appear-crash-in-dashboard/64550385#64550385) in a similar/duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434528/crashlytics-not-appear-crash-in-dashboard/64550385)

Answer (score 0):

After writing to support and waiting for half a day, the problem went away.
I did not receive a response from support, so may be it needed some time. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If using Dexguard, you can add that snippet at below. There is a good idea to follow this [discussion](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1944), everybody comments own solution because this upgrade create different affects for apps.

```
-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/service/meta-data@value=cct
```